# Bootstrap Navbar transparaent

Tags: file

this is my css ; how do i set the navbar header to transparent. I have tried to set `background-color; transparent;` but this don't change anything

```
.navbar-inner {


min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.navbar-inner {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 opacity: 0.6;
 filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 }
```

For more details check out [w3schools - CSS Image Opacity / Transparency](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)